# Parsing string based on last occurance of a delimiter (space in this case)

Tags: sql, teradata

How to parse string - last delimiter.

In Teradata I have name data stored in a varchar column.  I don't know how long the name could be, or how many pieces it could have: given name, potential multiple middle names (or no middle name), surname, etc.

I would like to parse the string, assuming everything after the last space in the name is the last name.  Anyone have any better ideas than mine?

Here is my solution:
(It's Hack-y, but it works, and avoids recursion, looping, udfs, etc.)

```
drop table tmp;
create volatile table tmp (str1 varchar(50)) on commit preserve rows;
insert into tmp values('mortecai ali von allen o''shae');
insert into tmp values('hillary rodham-clinton');
insert into tmp values('cher');
insert into tmp values('a.e. schatzschneider');

select str1
,length(str1)-length(oreplace(str1,' ','')) as occurrence
,(1-ABS(occurrence-0.1)/(occurrence-0.1))/2 
as if_occurence_is_0_return_1  
-- this just to handle the case that there are no spaces in the string at all
-- in the case of no spaces, assumes whole field is just last name
,occurrence+if_occurence_is_0_return_1
,instr(str1,' ',1,occurrence+if_occurence_is_0_return_1) as lastspace
,substr(str1,1,lastspace) as first_nm
,substr(str1,lastspace,length(str1)-lastspace+1) as last_nm
from tmp;

--pulling it all together 
--(just str1, first_nm & last_nm - no intermediate placeholder fields):
select str1
,substr(str1,1,instr(str1,' ',1,length(str1)-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))
+(1-ABS(length(str1)-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))-0.1)/(length(str1)
-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))-0.1))/2)) as first_nm
,substr(str1,instr(str1,' ',1,length(str1)-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))
+(1-ABS(length(str1)-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))-0.1)/(length(str1)
-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))-0.1))/2),length(str1)-instr(str1,' ',1,length(str1)
-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))+(1-ABS(length(str1)
-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))-0.1)/(length(str1)
-length(oreplace(str1,' ',''))-0.1))/2)+1) as last_nm
from tmp;
```

Comment: based on this method in [excel:] (http://www.bluemoosetech.com/microsoft-excel-functions.php?jid=32&title=Separating%20First%20and%20Last%20Names%20in%20Microsoft%20Excel)

Comment: TD14 has an [INSTR](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/String_Ops_Funcs.084.089.html) function, which may or may not help you.  Or you could use [STRTOK](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/String_Ops_Funcs.084.233.html) to split your string based on your delimter.

Comment: and how do you propose i find the LAST token, not knowing in advance how many are there? (without looping, without recursion, without special UDFs)

Comment: "`assuming everything after the last space in the name is the last name`". Under this plan, a name stored as `Martin Luther King Jr` would parse the last name as `Jr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using INSTR you're probably on TD14.

You should check the parameters for INSTR, you can search from backwards, too :-)

```
trim(substring(str1 from instr(str1,' ',-1,1))) as last_nm
```

The TRIM gets rid of the leading blank.

And the first name is

```
trim(substring(str1 from 1 for instr(str1,' ',-1,1))) as first_nm,
```

And of course you could also use a regular expression:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(str1, '[^ ]+$') as lst_nm,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(str1, '.*[ ]') as first_nm
```

Comment: Thanks Dieter!  Sometimes I get the feeling you are the only TD expert in the world who answers questions in the forums.  And aside from being omnipresent, and TD omniscient, do you ever sleep?  (:

Comment: It's almost 11 PM over here, so I'm not going to sleep, yet :-)  I just edited my answer and added the first names, too...

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting senile, I left out the searching backwards bit.